# Capturar valor de atributo filho usando xpath

Tags: php, xpath

Com xpath estou querendo pegar o valor do atributo do href abaixo, porem preciso ter certeza que será a url presente dentro da tag li.

```
    <li class="event">
<span class="mediaCoverageCont">
</span>
<a href="/esportes-futebol/liga-europa-201718-qualificação/1-102-1250545.html" class="24/08/2017 16:45:00">
<span class="imgOuter"><img alt="Dínamo Kiev x Maritimo" src="https://headlines-teams.s3.amazonaws.com/dinamo-de-kiev.png"/></span>
<span class="imgOuter" id="imgOuterRight"><img alt="Dínamo Kiev x Maritimo" src="https://headlines-teams.s3.amazonaws.com/maritimo.png"/></span>
<span class="currentTitle"><h3>Dínamo Kiev x Maritimo</h3></span>
<span class="currentDate"><img src="/s/images/headlines/currentDate.png" border="0" style="margin-right:3px;" align="center"/>24/08/2017 16:45:00</span>
</a>
```

Estou usando esse código mais nada é retornado, alguém sabe como posso estar resolvendo esse problema?

Parte do código que estou usando:

```
$link = $xpath->query('//li[@class="event" ]/a[@*]')->item(0);
```

Comment: Você quer retornar **/esportes-futebol/liga-europa-201718-qualificação/1-102-1250545.html** ?

Comment: @juniorb2ss sim

Comment: Conseguir o que precisava com esse código:

$link = $xpath->query('//td[@class="team"]/a/@href')->item(0)->nodeValue;`